# Create unique array from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that kinda looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => Random title
            [text_generic] => [b]This is Random title:[/b] 16 nov  2012
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
Some text goes here. Blaaaa
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 140309
            [headline] => Random title
            [body] => 
            [title_generic] => 
            [text_generic] => 
        )

)
```

I tried filtering it with `array_unique()`, but that only returns

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 140309
                [headline] => Random title
                [body] => 
                [title_generic] => 
                [text_generic] => 
            )
    )
```

But I'd like to have

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 140309
                [headline] => Random title
                [body] => 
                Some text goes here. Blaaaa
                [title_generic] => Random title
                [text_generic] => [b]This is Random title:[/b] 16 nov  2012
            )
    )
```

That is to return only unique fields that are all filled.

In the arrays there will be only one unique filled space, so there is no way that in first key I'll have `title_generic` and then I'll have different in third or so. The same is for `body` and `text_generic`. They appear only once in certain arrays. But id's, headline and such are always the same (there is a date inside and so on).

Is there a function that will do such a thing?

**EDIT**

I probably wasn't clear enough. I want to return array that has all the information from other keys (values from array in that key), that are different. So in first 4 keyes in the array I have the same array with `id`, `headline`, `body`, `title_generic` and `text_generic`. They have same id and headline and the rest are empty. Then in the next key the `title_generic` and `text_generic` are filled, and so on.

I need either array that will have filled keys like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 140309
                [headline] => Random title
                [body] => 
                Some text goes here. Blaaaa
                [title_generic] => Random title
                [text_generic] => [b]This is Random title:[/b] 16 nov  2012
            )
    )
```

or

```
Array
(
    [id] => 140309
    [headline] => Random title
    [body] => 
    Some text goes here. Blaaaa
    [title_generic] => Random title
    [text_generic] => [b]This is Random title:[/b] 16 nov  2012
)
```

I don't know how to explain this better...

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the logic again in simple terms? You want to return one of the arrays which is "unique" by some definition? Or you want to merge all those arrays into one where each field's value is chosen by some "uniqueness" criterion? And no, there's no built-in function which does either.

Comment: Well it depends. If the logic is that the additional information (e.g. `title_generic`, `text_generic` and so on) won't lead to conflicts (more than one different `title_generic` ...) you can do this. Otherwhise how would you solve the conflicts? e.g. Which title is the right one?

Comment: Sounds like you want to *merge* all the information into one array. You'll have to explain how to decide which piece of information to choose then if there are multiple to choose from ("conflict resolution" as @F.M says).

Comment: I tried `$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));` but this leaves me with 3 keys, one that has empty `body`, `title_generic` and `text_generic`, one with empty `title_generic` and `text_generic` and filled `body` and one with empty `body` but filled `title_generic` and `text_generic`.

Comment: @deceze there shouldn't be a conflict since they don't repeat in the other keys, only thing that repeats is `id` and `headline`. Should I just go with foreach, and filter out the empty ones and the ones that are repeating and just put it in a new array?

Comment: @dingo_d I would do this yes.

Comment: `array_unique( $array, SORT_REGULAR);` will give me those three unique, I guess I just need to go through them to make a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function (array $result, array $item) {
    return array_filter($result) + $item;
}, []);
```

This will probably do what you want (which is slightly unclear).

Explanation: It goes through each of your items one by one; it filters all empty values out of it, leaving only populated keys (`array_filter`); it then adds all keys which don't already exist (`+`) *from the next item* to it (read up on [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce)). The end result should be an array with all non-empty keys from all the arrays merged into one, with the value being the first non-empty value encountered within the loop.

Comment: This with `array_unique( $array, SORT_REGULAR);` and I just had to replace `[]` with `array()`, and it worked, kinda. I'll work on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already a solution for this. Nonetheless, I want to present you a lightweight approach in terms of execution time and with the same functionality.

```
# your data here
$array = [
  [
      'id' => '123',
      'headline' => 'one two three',
      'body' => 'somebody',
      'title_generic' => '',
      'text_generic' => '',
  ],
  [
      'id' => '123',
      'headline' => 'one two three',
      'body' => null,
      'title_generic' => 'title',
      'text_generic' => 'text',
  ],
];

# the aggregate to be created
$aggregate = [];

foreach ($array as $el) {
    if (empty($el)) continue;

    foreach ($el as $k => $v) {
        if (empty($v)) continue;

        if (!isset($aggregate[$k])) {
            $aggregate[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}

# debug print
echo '<pre>';print_r($aggregate);echo '<pre>';

# the output
Array
(
    [id] => 123
    [headline] => one two three
    [body] => somebody
    [title_generic] => title
    [text_generic] => text
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it turns out that I'll have to deal with this in totally different way (I neglected the fact that I have different ID's in my array :S)

Comment: @dingo_d do you need some further help then or could you solve it?

Comment: I managed to solve my issue with my sql query that was generating this array so I'm fine now :) Thanks